# Custom WPF context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I want to create a custom context menu that each item will have image on top and some text below it.

I know I can achieve this with with manipulating the template like so

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                 //do whatever here
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but in my program every control have same basic template that all of the control of the same type(here its contextmenu) inherit from it, and I don't want to ruin it by overriding the template here

is there anyway i can achieve what i want without changing the template?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `key` in your style.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" x:key="CustomContextMenu">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                 //do whatever here
           </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

And apply it like this.

```xml
<Button Content="Right" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource CustomContextMenu}">
            <MenuItem Header="File" />
            <MenuItem Header="Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="SaveAs" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: wont this override my default style?(for the  ContextMenu I'm applying the style on it)

Comment: No, it won't. This is an [Explicit Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-styles#apply-an-implicit-or-explicit-style).